# Integrating SAML2 Shibboleth with a Blazor Server application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I need to integrate SAML2 Shibboleth with my Blazor Server application, which is currently logged in with the default ASP.NET Identity.
The application is hosted on a server where, when the url "/Secure" is requested, it is automatically redirected by the server to the idp.
With this, I want to receive the login data in order to create a login for that user.